# Should i work with INode or Node in Umbraco?

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco

In many Umbraco examples i see two different approaches for the same types of work. Sometimes people select, query and return **INode**. Other people do everything with **Node**.

Can anyone tell me which is the preferred way of working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Umbraco, but I don't think that the answer has to be specific to it.

If you return `INode`, it gives you flexibility in the future in that you can return (internally) any class that extends from `INode`.  if `INode` contains all properties and methods of `Node`, then no functionality is lost from doing this.

Take for example, the opportunity of using `IEnumerable` vs `List`

```
IEnumerable<int> x = MyClass.MyMethod();
```

Both the following definitions of `MyMethod` would be valid in this class example.

```
public static IEnumerable<int> MyMethod()
{
    return new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
}

....

public static IEnumerable<int> MyMethod()
{
    return new int[] {1, 2, 3};
}
```

This lets you change the implementation of `MyMethod` without having to modify each caller.

For your methods, you should return the simplest type that gives all the functionality relavant to its context.  Say if you need to modify the list that `MyMethod` returns, then returning `IEnumerable` is a bad choice (as it's immutable).

Answer (score 0):

Like Matthew says, it depends what you are trying to achieve.

But if you are a beginner and don't know what you are doing, I suggest you return Node because otherwise at some point you may well have to cast your INode back to a Node (which is not necessarily a big problem, but would usually defeat the purpose of returning INode in the first place as you would be coupling your code to the non-abstracted Node class).